# Is there any good JAVA lib for playing with WSDL's and WS-* bindings?

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, data-binding, wsdl

Is there any good JAVA lib for playing with reading from WSDL's and connecting to WS-* bindings?

Comment: What's the game name where you need sockets, http-protocol, web-services and video-streaming at the same time?

Comment: @FarmBoy - What makes him a fool?

Comment: Seven questions in an hour?  All vague and hardly related?

Comment: Must admit I've wondered about the somewhat wide ranging and scatter gun selection of questions as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Apache Axis2](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/) - one of the most popular java webservices framework. It has multiple Java - XML binding methods (e.g. JAXB, ADB).

A good alternative would be [Metro](https://metro.dev.java.net/) (from Sun, part of the GlassFish stack) or [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) (previously called XFire)

For a summary: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_frameworks)

Answer (score 0):

Does [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) or [Apache Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/) suit your needs?

Comment: Would you give an example with source on how to use them please.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want play and write WSDL elements you can use Wsdl4J JSR implementation which is what even Axis uses behind the scene.
This gives u a nice API to read and write WSDL elements