# How to read WSDL in Java

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I have a URL that returns an XML file in WSDL format. How can I parse the response? Is there a class in Java standard library that I can use?

Comment: Yes, try one of these: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+soap+client&oq=java+soap+client&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.8135j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: For xml parsing you can use java xml parsers like Stax or by using JAX-B.

But my doubt is that after you parsing the wsdl what you will do?

I am thinking you want to call the web service that is exposed through WSDL .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any good JAVA lib for playing with WSDL's and WS-\* bindings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525636/is-there-any-good-java-lib-for-playing-with-wsdls-and-ws-bindings)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate Web Service client codes (Classes required to call web service) by using **wsimport** utility which is present in JDK 6 or later.

In terminal you can fire

```
wsimport -keep -verbose <your wsdl url>

ex :
wsimport -keep -verbose http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?wsdl
```

The above command will generate required classes to call web service .You just need to call some methods to access the web service .

If any help required please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I used `JAXB` for parsing the response of XML to Java.

An example for acheiving the same is mentioned [here](http://duckranger.com/2011/06/jaxb-without-a-schema/). I probably would suggest you to go through the [JAXB Documentation](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.5/docs/ch03.html#unmarshalling) and surely you will be able to work out with your problem.